# Changing Hue on a certain part of a mesh in a Texture Atlas?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, color

I want to change the hue and the saturation on these green tree tops,but the grid lacks the tone I want them to have, that'd be a tone between teal and green, the problem is that these trees share the same material because I read atlas texturing is the best way to texture low-poly models, and I wonder if there is a procedural method to get a slightly different tone with nodes or masks, and maintaining it as optimized as possible.

I know there is a color palette in Unity but I'm planning on working with Unreal Engine so that's not an option.

I am a beginner using Blender and I know the basics of node texturing but I can't find a solution out there. Any help would be much appreciated.[image: These are the tree tops and as I said before I would like to change just the green ones]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having two UV maps you can use the color grid image for masking. Or use a separate mask image with different mask shapes (linear gradient, spheric gradient, full black, full white, etc) and pack it into the alpha channel of the grid image. For the example, I've just used the color grid.

UV map for the color as you already have it:

[image: UV map color]

Another UV map for the mask:

[image: UV map mask]

With help of the *Hue Saturation Value* node can change the color. Let's make the green top of the tree purple:

[image: color adjustment]

Comment: Ok I think I get it, this would be the first step, then I would need to bake this within an atlas with the other trees and I would have all my vegetation with one material and one texture but different colors, just like in mobile videogames production. Sometimes I forget basic steps when trying to go quick haha Thank you so much!!

Comment: @rua95 Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum, please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).